# Pandas: Non overlapping datetimes algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I have a pandas dataframe (see input below) with multiple columns the important columns are start_datetime and end_datetime. The algorithm that I want to apply is the following. I compare every line to its next line. If the end_datetime (current line) is exceeding the start_datetime (next line) I want to move the row to the end. And then compare the current_line to the next line, which was the second next before. And I want to repeat this process until I have blocks of rows in which the time is non-overlapping. It is important that due to moving the problematic row to the end a jump in the datetimes will be present which will start as a new non-overlapping block. I have an example data set with input, step 1, step 2, and output.

I tried to solve it with this for loop but I am not able to adapt it in such way that it completes the task. The indices are confusing me. Maybe there is a built in pandas solution to this?

```
for i in range(0, df_temp.shape[0] - 1):
    if df_temp.iloc[i+1].start_datetime < df_temp.iloc[i].end_datetime:
        df_temp = df_temp.reindex([index for index in df_temp.index if index != i + 1] + [i + 1], axis=0)

df_temp.to_csv("output.csv", header=True, index=False)
```

## input

```
start_datetime          end_datetime
2023-01-01 00:55:13.000 2023-01-01 01:17:56.000
2023-01-01 01:29:57.000 2023-01-01 01:30:24.000
2023-01-01 01:30:55.000 2023-01-01 01:31:33.000
2023-01-01 01:32:05.000 2023-01-01 01:32:44.000
2023-01-01 01:33:59.000 2023-01-01 02:13:24.000
2023-01-01 04:59:59.000 2023-01-01 05:15:48.000
2023-01-01 05:54:04.000 2023-01-01 06:15:53.000
2023-01-01 06:05:56.000 2023-01-01 06:06:02.000 <-- will be shifted to end
2023-01-01 06:06:58.000 2023-01-01 06:42:34.000
2023-01-01 06:08:39.000 2023-01-01 06:31:53.000
2023-01-01 06:16:16.000 2023-01-01 06:39:13.000
2023-01-01 06:30:36.000 2023-01-01 06:38:15.000
2023-01-01 06:32:48.000 2023-01-01 06:49:34.000
2023-01-01 06:35:17.000 2023-01-01 07:02:44.000
2023-01-01 06:59:56.000 2023-01-01 07:47:47.000
2023-01-01 07:17:07.000 2023-01-01 07:20:11.000
2023-01-01 07:22:04.000 2023-01-01 07:57:34.000
2023-01-01 07:24:07.000 2023-01-01 07:54:18.000
2023-01-01 07:36:41.000 2023-01-01 08:07:18.000
2023-01-01 09:24:12.000 2023-01-01 09:46:57.000
2023-01-01 09:26:30.000 2023-01-01 09:58:42.000
2023-01-01 09:31:27.000 2023-01-01 10:00:19.000
```

## step 1

```
start_datetime          end_datetime
2023-01-01 00:55:13.000 2023-01-01 01:17:56.000
2023-01-01 01:29:57.000 2023-01-01 01:30:24.000
2023-01-01 01:30:55.000 2023-01-01 01:31:33.000
2023-01-01 01:32:05.000 2023-01-01 01:32:44.000
2023-01-01 01:33:59.000 2023-01-01 02:13:24.000
2023-01-01 04:59:59.000 2023-01-01 05:15:48.000
2023-01-01 05:54:04.000 2023-01-01 06:15:53.000
2023-01-01 06:06:58.000 2023-01-01 06:42:34.000 <-- will be shifted to end
2023-01-01 06:08:39.000 2023-01-01 06:31:53.000
2023-01-01 06:16:16.000 2023-01-01 06:39:13.000
2023-01-01 06:30:36.000 2023-01-01 06:38:15.000
2023-01-01 06:32:48.000 2023-01-01 06:49:34.000
2023-01-01 06:35:17.000 2023-01-01 07:02:44.000
2023-01-01 06:59:56.000 2023-01-01 07:47:47.000
2023-01-01 07:17:07.000 2023-01-01 07:20:11.000
2023-01-01 07:22:04.000 2023-01-01 07:57:34.000
2023-01-01 07:24:07.000 2023-01-01 07:54:18.000
2023-01-01 07:36:41.000 2023-01-01 08:07:18.000
2023-01-01 09:24:12.000 2023-01-01 09:46:57.000
2023-01-01 09:26:30.000 2023-01-01 09:58:42.000
2023-01-01 09:31:27.000 2023-01-01 10:00:19.000
2023-01-01 06:05:56.000 2023-01-01 06:06:02.000
```

## step 2

```
start_datetime          end_datetime
2023-01-01 00:55:13.000 2023-01-01 01:17:56.000
2023-01-01 01:29:57.000 2023-01-01 01:30:24.000
2023-01-01 01:30:55.000 2023-01-01 01:31:33.000
2023-01-01 01:32:05.000 2023-01-01 01:32:44.000
2023-01-01 01:33:59.000 2023-01-01 02:13:24.000
2023-01-01 04:59:59.000 2023-01-01 05:15:48.000
2023-01-01 05:54:04.000 2023-01-01 06:15:53.000
2023-01-01 06:08:39.000 2023-01-01 06:31:53.000 <-- will be shifted to end
2023-01-01 06:16:16.000 2023-01-01 06:39:13.000
2023-01-01 06:30:36.000 2023-01-01 06:38:15.000
2023-01-01 06:32:48.000 2023-01-01 06:49:34.000
2023-01-01 06:35:17.000 2023-01-01 07:02:44.000
2023-01-01 06:59:56.000 2023-01-01 07:47:47.000
2023-01-01 07:17:07.000 2023-01-01 07:20:11.000
2023-01-01 07:22:04.000 2023-01-01 07:57:34.000
2023-01-01 07:24:07.000 2023-01-01 07:54:18.000
2023-01-01 07:36:41.000 2023-01-01 08:07:18.000
2023-01-01 09:24:12.000 2023-01-01 09:46:57.000
2023-01-01 09:26:30.000 2023-01-01 09:58:42.000
2023-01-01 09:31:27.000 2023-01-01 10:00:19.000
2023-01-01 06:05:56.000 2023-01-01 06:06:02.000
2023-01-01 06:06:58.000 2023-01-01 06:42:34.000
```

## output

```
start_datetime          end_datetime
2023-01-01 00:55:13.000 2023-01-01 01:17:56.000 <-- Start of first sequence
2023-01-01 01:29:57.000 2023-01-01 01:30:24.000
2023-01-01 01:30:55.000 2023-01-01 01:31:33.000
2023-01-01 01:32:05.000 2023-01-01 01:32:44.000
2023-01-01 01:33:59.000 2023-01-01 02:13:24.000
2023-01-01 04:59:59.000 2023-01-01 05:15:48.000
2023-01-01 05:54:04.000 2023-01-01 06:15:53.000
2023-01-01 06:16:16.000 2023-01-01 06:39:13.000
2023-01-01 06:59:56.000 2023-01-01 07:47:47.000
2023-01-01 09:24:12.000 2023-01-01 09:46:57.000 <-- End of first sequence without overlap
2023-01-01 06:05:56.000 2023-01-01 06:06:02.000 <-- Start of second sequence
2023-01-01 06:08:39.000 2023-01-01 06:31:53.000
2023-01-01 06:32:48.000 2023-01-01 06:49:34.000
2023-01-01 07:17:07.000 2023-01-01 07:20:11.000
2023-01-01 07:22:04.000 2023-01-01 07:57:34.000
2023-01-01 09:26:30.000 2023-01-01 09:58:42.000 <-- End of second sequence
2023-01-01 06:06:58.000 2023-01-01 06:42:34.000 <-- Start of third sequence
2023-01-01 07:24:07.000 2023-01-01 07:54:18.000
2023-01-01 09:31:27.000 2023-01-01 10:00:19.000 <-- End of third sequence
2023-01-01 06:30:36.000 2023-01-01 06:38:15.000 <-- Start of fourth sequence
2023-01-01 06:35:17.000 2023-01-01 07:02:44.000
2023-01-01 07:36:41.000 2023-01-01 08:07:18.000 <-- End of fourth sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably heard the "avoid loops! Prefer to vectorize" advice.

Pandas has a great many functions, and it can be hard to know which one applies
to a given business problem. Here, you want
[shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html).

Synthesize a new column containing the shifted timestamp:
`df_temp["shifted"] = df_temp.start_datetime.shift(-1)`.
You may find it convenient to `.dropna()`.

Now you can implement the algorithm you outlined
by examining each row in isolation.
Synthesize one more timestamp column,
and use *that* to arrange for some rows to be re-ordered. When you
[sort](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)
by timestamp you'll have certain rows pushed toward the end as you wanted.

---

There are some algorithmic details that your English prose and,
surprisingly, your code, do not clear up.

Recommend you write a helper function that ends with a `yield`:

```
def rearrange_intervals(input_rows):
    buffer = []  # (or whatever you need, to remember pending rows)
    for i, row in enumerate(input_rows):
        ...  # evaluate current and nearby rows
        yield dict(start_datetime= ... ,
                   end_datetime= ... )
```

With that generator in hand it's trivial to gather the results using
`df = pd.DataFrame(rearrange_intervals(input_rows))`.

I suggest this approach so you're free to arbitrarily
insert / delete / rearrange rows at will,
without worrying about expensive dataframe slicing / copying.

You mention details like "third sequence" and "fourth sequence".
Consider creating an integer column which records those numbers
and which can participate in a multi-column sort order.

Comment: Hi J_H, the issue with the new column is that sometimes I have to compare the current row to multiple following rows. I had this additional column but it didn't help me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I know that the implementation of the algorithm can be more efficient. But I just need the job to be done :D.

I solved the problem the following way. First, create a function to remove everything which is overlapping. And repeat the step if you removed a row such that a comparison with the next row is still possible. I introduced an index which will then be used to divide the data into a part which is ordered and overlapping and a second part which is ordered but might be overlapping.

```
import uuid
import pandas


def order_data(df):
    df_temp = df.copy()
    for index in range(0, df_temp.shape[0] - 1):
        while True:
            try:
                if df_temp.iloc[index+1].start_datetime< df_temp.iloc[index].end_datetime:
                    df_temp = df_temp.drop(index=(index + 1))
                    df_temp = df_temp.reset_index(drop=True)
                else:
                    break
            except IndexError:
                break
    return df_temp, df.copy()[~df.index_ref.isin(df_temp.index_ref.values)].drop(columns=["index_ref"]).reset_index(names='index_ref', drop=False)
```

Then I defined a loop to collect all dataframes. I also introduced a uuid column to tag the blocks for a block of non-overlapping rows.

```py
dfs: list[pandas.DataFrame] = []

while True:
    df_temp, df_removed = order_data(df)
    dfs.append(df_temp.assign(uuid=str(uuid.uuid4())))
    if df_removed.shape[0] != 0:
        df = df_removed.copy()
    else:
        break

pandas.concat(dfs).to_csv("ordered.csv", header=True, index=False)
```